# Update database record on a specific date

Tags: mysql, database, events, cron

I have an attribute in MYSQL database called "`dueDate`". I want to update the record on the due date at `11:59PM`. 
Is there a way to create an `event` or `cronjob` that could do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an event, or cronjob, for any particular time, if your system administration allows you to use either facility. It's easy to look up how to create a MySQL repeating event.

But this is a *brittle* way of dealing with time dependencies in your business rules.  What do I mean "brittle?"  For one thing, if something goes wrong and the job doesn't run, your business rules are fouled up and need to be repaired.  For another thing, cronjobs and events don't *run* at precise times of day, they run *on or after* that time of day. They can take awhile to start.

So, I suggest you use rules in a query to enforce your business rules.  Suppose, for example, your original desire is to set a column called `is_overdue` to `1` at the end of the due date.  Instead, use a query like this to compute your `is_overdue` column.

```
   SELECT whatever, dueDate,
          IF(dueDate >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY, 1, 0) is_overdue
     FROM table ...
```

This has the advantage that it will always be correct, down to the millisecond, and won't depend on the running of a brittle background job.

Events and cronjobs are better used for purging of stale records. For example, you can get rid of any records that have been expired for 30 days or more by using this kind of query in them.

```
  DELETE FROM table WHERE dueDate <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

If your cronjob / event fails to run on a particular day, the next day's run will still do the cleanup correctly.

**Edit**. The point of this suggestion is to *compute* the time-dependent column (`is_expired` in the example). If you follow this suggestion, you won't update the table at all. Instead, you'll use the suggested query *whenever* you retrieve the `is_expired` value.

**Pro tip**. When you want to do something at a time `<=` the last moment of a particular day, you're better off doing it at a time `<` the first moment of the next day.  That is, for best results use

```
   WHERE dueDate < '2017-11-17' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

in place of

```
   WHERE dueDate <= '2017-11-17 23:59:59'
```

Why? the last moment of a day is hard to express precisely, especially if your system's timing using subsecond precision. But the first moment of a day is easy to express precisely.

Comment: Is it possible to add rules in an INSERT statement instead of a query?

Comment: The point of putting rules in a query is this: the query runs at a particular time reflected by `CURDATE()`.  You could build the rules into a computed column (in recent MySQL versions) or into a VIEW. But not the insert.

Comment: Is it a good solution to add this " SELECT whatever, dueDate,
          IF(dueDate >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY, 1, 0) is_overdue
     FROM table ..." in an event that runs once a day at 11:59? If not, where exactly do I need to add this query in order to update the record when the due date is reached?